# How to get inactive customer count accounting for customer creation date?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have a sales fact table that contains customers ids and is linked to customers dimension table that contains all registered customers in the system with entry/ customer creation dates. Sales fact table has active relationship with Dates table by sales date.

How to write a measure that could give inactive customer count in selected period, accounting for customer creation date that does not have relation to Dates table?

i.e. Active customers  - distinctcount of customer id in Sales fact table.
Inactive customers - countrows of customer id in Customer table, if customer id not present in Sales fact table and if the creation date-time of the customer in Customers table is < than the Max date of the selected period in Date table.

From visuals I will have cards displaying active, inactive customer count in selected period
+ matrix that should contain list of all customer names (active, inactive) with sales amounts by year-month. When selecting periods, matrix should contain only inactive customer names that were registered in the system before max date of selected period. It cannot display all customers from Customers dimension table. Is this possible?

Would highly appreciate your help!

Comment: Sorry, noticed that inactive customer definition missed a part of the sentence - Inactive customers - countrows of customer id in Customer table, if customer id not present in Sales fact table and if the creation date-time of the customer in Customers table is < than the Max date of the selected period in Date table.

Comment: Please add your example table data, it is difficult from the text to understand exactly what you are looking for.